# How to get firestore document from android service (FirebaseMessagingService)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I have a FirebaseMessagingService derived service in my android app that receives firebase messages (via onMessageReceived) and then gets a firestore document with the ID provided in the received message.

The problem is that sometimes, the document can't be retrieved from firestore; I get the error message "**Failed to get document because the client is offline**".

I tried auto-retrying to get the document every 10sec for up to 5 minutes, but without success. I noticed that the code does not seem to have access to internet when it happens (but the reception of the message required internet, right!?). Weird thing is that during this 5 minutes, other message get received and their document gets retrieved successfully...

I don't think it matters but the issue happens on my WIFI and on LTE, so it ain't a internet provider issue.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this? I've been struggling for a couple of weeks on this issue...

Here's the code:

```
class ReceptionService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(itemMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        itemMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {
            val notifContent = GZIPInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(itemMessage.data["content"]!!.toByteArray())
                    .inputStream()).bufferedReader(UTF_8).use { it.readText() }
            when {
                // Convert Message into NotifParam
                val gsonContent = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Calendar::class.java, DotNetDateDeserializer()).create()
                val resultDataType = object : TypeToken<NotifParam>() {}.type

                val documentId = gsonContent.fromJson(notifContent, resultDataType).DocumentId

                doAsync {
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Item").document(documentId).get(Source.SERVER)
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Notification.notifyAlert(applicationContext, "Error: can't get document")
                        }
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot -> ... }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Firebase SDK are you using?

Comment: "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx: 21.0.0" and "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx: 22.0.0"

Comment: Did you tried to run a simple hello world with a basic hardcoded [get document function](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/3737165276893cb42a3014f96f802cdedf7e53f2/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/kotlin/DocSnippets.kt#L463-L474), this is in order to check if something in the project is misconfigured. in debug mode can you see any warning or error log? in AVD are able to see the same behaviour?

Comment: @JanHernandez I tried with a simple app, without success and I could not see any information leading to the issue in debug mode (on my device and in an emulator)... I managed to setup a retry ping-pong between the server and the client and it seems to work properly but this is an ugly solution... Any other ideas?